# What should be the input/output format for java code at relevel's test ide?

Tags: java, data-structures, ide, cp

The code I wrote in Java used to give perfect output on local ide but not accepted by relevel's ide.After watching lot of YT videos I came to know that one should take care of input and output format while coding for relevel's test,so what is that format?Does anyone knows as I am new to cp.

Comment: There are some instances where if you copy paste code between ide and software(s) like MS Word etc the character encoding changes like quote changes to something else which won't be recognized by ide once you paste it back.

Comment: share details/screenshots of the softwares you're using to code and copy/paste if any?